# passing a modelAttribute to an AJAX method

Tags: java, ajax, spring, portlet, modelattribute

I'm quite new using Spring and AJAX with JQuery, and I'm having some troubles with it.

I need to fill one combobox, depending the value of another combobox in the jsp. I need some values from the jsp bean, so I need to pass the bean to the Ajax call.

I'm trying to do something like this in my jsp:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function getData() {

    var myBean = '${myBean}';

    jQ.getJSON("<c:out escapeXml="false" value='${ajaxMyMethod}'/>",
               {myBean: myBean},
               function(data) { 
                 // fill the combo
                 ...
    })

</script>

<form:form id="formMyForm" action="${formAction}" method="post" modelAttribute="myBean" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form:form>
```

And in my controller:

```
@ResourceMapping(value = "ajaxMyMethod")
public final JsonCombomyCombo getData(@RequestParam MyBean myBean) {
    ...
}
```

But I don't reach the `getData` method, and it throws an `org.springframework.web.portlet.NoHandlerFoundException`:

> No matching handler method found for portlet request: mode 'view',
>   phase 'RESOURCE_PHASE', parameters map['myBean' -> -> array['MyBean[...

I really would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `${ajaxMyMethod}`? Does the form have an element with the name `myBean`?

Comment: "MyBean" is the Model Attribute and the problem has nothing to do with the "ajaxMyMethod" value (let's say is any string you like). 
Why are you asking this?

Comment: I was thinking Spring MVC. Nevermind.